# Python || Pandas || How to put multiple conditions in Lambda

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I have two columns called "Status" & "DELTA_TIME", I want to create a new column called "Past Minute" and I wish to add values based on the below conditions.

- If the status is Open & Checkin and DELTA_TIME is below 30, the "Past_Minute" value should     be blank
- If the status is Open & Checkin and DELTA_TIME is between 30 & 60, the "Past_Minute" value should be "30 Mins Delay"
- If the status is Open & Checkin and DELTA_TIME is between 60 & 90, the "Past_Minute" value should be "60 Mins Delay"
- If the status is Open & Checkin and DELTA_TIME is above 90, the "Past_Minute" value should be "90 Mins Delay"

**Here is my data frame**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Status':['Closed','Open', 'Open','Cancel','Closed','Cancel', 'Checkin', 'Open', 'Open', 'Checkin', 'Open'], 
                   'DELTA_TIME':[-3, -1, 0, 5, 55, 40, 70, 80, 90, 100, 44]})
     Status  DELTA_TIME
0    Closed          -3
1      Open          -1
2      Open           0
3    Cancel           5
4    Closed          55
5    Cancel          40
6   Checkin          70
7      Open          80
8      Open          90
9   Checkin         100
10     Open          44
```

**and here is my expectation of data.**

```
     Status  DELTA_TIME    Past_Minute
0    Closed          -3               
1      Open          -1               
2      Open           0               
3    Cancel           5               
4    Closed          55  
5    Cancel          40  
6   Checkin          70  60 Mins Delay
7      Open          80  60 Mins Delay
8      Open          90  90 Mins Delay
9   Checkin         100  90 Mins Delay
10     Open          44  30 Mins Delay
```

**1st Method:-** I tried using loc to get the "Past_Minute" column values as below.

```
df.loc[(df['Status'] == 'Open') | (df['Status'] == 'Checkin') & (df['DELTA_TIME'] <30.00), "Past_Minute"] = ''
df.loc[(df['Status'] == 'Open') | (df['Status'] == 'Checkin') & (df['DELTA_TIME'] > 30.00) & (df['DELTA_TIME'] < 60.00), "Past_Minute"] = '30 Mins Delay'
df.loc[(df['Status'] == 'Open') | (df['Status'] == 'Checkin') & (df['DELTA_TIME'] >=60.00) & (df['DELTA_TIME'] < 90.00), "Past_Minute"] = '60 Mins Delay'
df.loc[(df['Status'] == 'Open') | (df['Status'] == 'Checkin') & (df['DELTA_TIME'] >=90.00), "Past_Minute"] = '90 Mins Delay'

print(df)
```

**And here is the result.**

```
     Status  DELTA_TIME    Past_Minute
0    Closed          -3            NaN
1      Open          -1  90 Mins Delay
2      Open           0  90 Mins Delay
3    Cancel           5            NaN
4    Closed          55            NaN
5    Cancel          40            NaN
6   Checkin          70  60 Mins Delay
7      Open          80  90 Mins Delay
8      Open          90  90 Mins Delay
9   Checkin         100  90 Mins Delay
10     Open          44  90 Mins Delay
[Finished in 0.9s]
```

You see here only 60 Mins delay & 90 mins delay is coming. 30 mins delay & Blank is not at all coming for less than 30 and between 30 to 60. though I have less than 30 and a few negative numbers as well.

**2nd Method:-** I tried to use Lambda and it worked pretty well based on DELTA_TiME column, however, I am not able to add the Status column in the equation to filter it further.

```
df['Past_Minute'] = df['DELTA_TIME'].apply(lambda x : '30 Mins Delay' if x>30 and x<60 else '60 Mins Delay' if x>60 and x<90 else '90 Mins Delay' if x>=90 else "")
```

**here is 2nd result.**

```
    Status  DELTA_TIME    Past_Minute
0    Closed          -3               
1      Open          -1               
2      Open           0               
3    Cancel           5               
4    Closed          55  30 Mins Delay
5    Cancel          40  30 Mins Delay
6   Checkin          70  60 Mins Delay
7      Open          80  60 Mins Delay
8      Open          90  90 Mins Delay
9   Checkin         100  90 Mins Delay
10     Open          44  30 Mins Delay
[Finished in 0.9s]
```

You see, here I am definitely getting precise values that I want, based on my requirement, except I am not able to fit Status in the equation. For example, lines 4 and 5 should not have the values in the **"Past Minute"** column, because the status is not "Open" or "checkin".

Can anyone help me in fixing the Lambda for me or guide me to the right way to meet the conditions?

Comment: Will it cause you to drop dead if you just define a function (`def get_past_minute(status, delta_time): ...`) and use that?

Comment: Hi @ThePhoton - Thanks for the suggestions, however, I am a beginner in python, hence I do most of things with the help of the internet, I tried creating a function as well. Unfortunately, I could not create a working one for myself. Would it be to much to ask if you could create a simple function to demo the above requirement and I would further modify it? I would really appreciate your help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are nearly there , but use apply on entire df and by passing [axis=1](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) we mean we want to pass entire row as lambda parameter not just one column value

```
df['Past_Minute'] = df.apply(lambda row:  ('30 Mins Delay' if row['DELTA_TIME']>30 and row['DELTA_TIME']<60 else '60 Mins Delay' if row['DELTA_TIME']>60 and row['DELTA_TIME']<90 else '90 Mins Delay' if row['DELTA_TIME']>=90 else "") if row['Status'] in ['Open','Checkin'] else "",axis = 1)
df
Out[16]: 
     Status  DELTA_TIME    Past_Minute
0    Closed          -3               
1      Open          -1               
2      Open           0               
3    Cancel           5               
4    Closed          55               
5    Cancel          40               
6   Checkin          70  60 Mins Delay
7      Open          80  60 Mins Delay
8      Open          90  90 Mins Delay
9   Checkin         100  90 Mins Delay
10     Open          44  30 Mins Delay
```

Comment: Thank you so much bhai for the help, it actually did wonders. It works perfectly as expected. Thank you so much once again Surjit bhai... Cheers... 

Answer (score 1):

You aren't limited to `lambda` syntax for the `apply` method. For more complex tasks such as the one in the question, you can create a full function and pass it to `apply`.

Here's a mock DataFrame and an example use:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.util.testing.makeMixedDataFrame()
df.head()

     A    B     C          D
0  0.0  0.0  foo1 2009-01-01
1  1.0  1.0  foo2 2009-01-02
2  2.0  0.0  foo3 2009-01-05
3  3.0  1.0  foo4 2009-01-06
4  4.0  0.0  foo5 2009-01-07
```

Here's a partial function that checks several different conditions and returns a boolean value. You can modify the function however you want.

```py
def apply_func(x):
    if x["A"] <= 2.0 and x["B"] <= 2.0:
        return True
    elif x["C"] == "foo4":
        return True
    else:
        return False

df["new_col"] = df.apply(apply_func, axis=1)
df.head()

     A    B     C          D  new_col
0  0.0  0.0  foo1 2009-01-01     True
1  1.0  1.0  foo2 2009-01-02     True
2  2.0  0.0  foo3 2009-01-05     True
3  3.0  1.0  foo4 2009-01-06     True
4  4.0  0.0  foo5 2009-01-07    False
```